# Assign values to array when a checkbox is checked VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, checkbox, basic

I have check boxes named checkbox_1, checkbox_2 .... up to checkbox_10. I want to create a loop to store: 1 if the checkbox is checked and 0 if the checkbox is not checked- in the locations(10) array.

Comment: If you have 10 checkboxes, your array will need to be `locations(9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be done with something like:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("checkbox_" & i, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is CheckBox Then
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(matches(0), CheckBox)
        Locations(i - 1) = IIf(cb.Checked, 1, 0)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!